# C++: Methods repeating themselves; DRY optimization needed

Tags: c++, dry

The three initialize methods of this class are very, very, very similar.  I'd like to see if there's a way to chain the calls together, potentially into the method that requires both arguments. Thanks.

AudioHandler.h

```
class AudioHandler {

public:
    static bool Initialize(const SoundLibrary& sl);
    static bool Initialize(const Soundtrack& st);
    static bool Initialize(const SoundLibrary& sl, const Soundtrack& st);
    static void Release();
private:
    static const SoundLibrary* _sl;
    static const Soundtrack* _st;
};
```

AudioHandler.cpp

```
bool AudioHandler::Initialize(const SoundLibrary& sl) {
    if(_sl != NULL || _st != NULL) return false;

    unsigned long numVoices = 0;

    //If allegro is unable to initialize the sound drivers then return false.
    if((numVoices = detect_digi_driver(DIGI_AUTODETECT)) == 0) return false;
    if(install_sound(DIGI_AUTODETECT, MIDI_NONE, NULL) == -1) return false;
    _sl = &sl;

    return true;
}

bool AudioHandler::Initialize(const Soundtrack& st) {
    if(_sl != NULL || _st != NULL) return false;

    if(detect_midi_driver(MIDI_AUTODETECT) == 0) return false;
    if(install_sound(DIGI_NONE, MIDI_AUTODETECT, NULL) == -1) return false;
    _st = &st;

    return true;
}

bool AudioHandler::Initialize(const SoundLibrary& sl, const Soundtrack& st) {
    if(_sl != NULL || _st != NULL) return false;

    unsigned long numVoices = 0;

    if((numVoices = detect_digi_driver(DIGI_AUTODETECT)) == 0) return false;
    if(detect_midi_driver(MIDI_AUTODETECT) == 0) return false;
    if(install_sound(DIGI_AUTODETECT, MIDI_AUTODETECT, NULL) == -1) return false;

    _sl = &sl;
    _st = &st;

    return true;
}

void AudioHandler::Release() {
    _sl = NULL;
    _st = NULL;
    remove_sound();
}
```

Comment: Why is that a class, and not a namespace?

Comment: Storing the address of a constant reference is very dangerous. You have no idea that the object actually lives after the function call.

Comment: @KerrekSB What would it being a namespace accomplish?

Comment: It's just a bit odd to have a class without a state just for the purpose of exposing some functions. Then you might as well not have a class and instead put the functions in a namespace. It's a minor point, more of a note that this may warrant thinking about. What you have is certainly one possible way to design this.

Comment: @KerrekSB Keep in mind that before it was suggested to remove the reference pointers that it did have state: The reference pointers. I've since taken Krizz's advice and yours as well and changed them to be included in the namespace of the project without being in a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Leave 3rd variant only.
2. Change references to pointers.
3. Send `NULL` for the arguments you don't need.
4. Check for `NULL` before doing specific code.

PS: in your current version, storing the address of a passed reference in the object is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

These are quite short functions so I have to wonder if it would be worth the time or effort to modify the code. But I'd probably want to do it too. You could make another private function that the other three call with certain parameters to do all the operations they have in common. That way the common operations are in one place. It's up to you whether or not it would be worthwhile. If you're worried about maintenence in the future, then go for it.

Comment: Ah, after looking more closely I see that the parameters to the functions these functions call aren't the only difference. Rather, the function calls themselves are different and only depend on the type of the input. In that case you might just want to do as Krizz said and keep the third function. Only execute a test if the pointer passed to the function isn't NULL.